# External command to force ofstream to flush

Tags: filesystems, command, c++

I have a C++ ofstream that, for performance reasons, I don't flush from inside the code.  However, occasionally I need to inspect the file contents.  Is there a Linux command that will force the stream to flush to the file?  (I.e., while the writing program is still running and holding the stream open.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a Linux command that will force the stream to flush to the file?

Not really, but the standard approach is to install a signal handler for, say, `SIGUSR1`.  The signal handler would set a flag, then your program would check the flag once in a while, and flush the relevant streams, and perhaps also print some relevant state information.